# Kubernetes, external Load balancer + Nginx Ingress Controller, preserve IP address with Ingress

Tags: kubernetes, networking, haproxy, nginx-ingress

I have an external HAproxy configured, and a cluster of kubernetes nodes (1 master & 3 workers).

Haproxy is configured in Trasparent mode, A.K.A. I get the real ip address of client on the nodes that are behind HAproxy. This is verified with tcpdump on the kubernetes master node, and trying to connect from outside HAproxy. All other worker nodes get the real ip too.

Now, I want that all Pods Deployed in the K8s cluster receive the real ip address of the clients too. This has been problematic to say the least (Kubernetes can you please be simpler??)

I have followed this example: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/services/source-ip/

With a nodeport service, and the service patched with:

`kubectl patch svc nodeport -p '{"spec":{"externalTrafficPolicy":"Local"}}'`

I get the real ip of the client.

The problem is that the example doesn't mention what to do if you connect through the Ingress controller.

I have improvised an ingress.yaml (i'm using tls termination at the ingress controller as well)

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ip-ingress
  namespace: default
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
     - "myip.mydomain.com"
    secretName: filewithcertificate
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: "myip.mydomain.com"
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/"
        backend:
          service:
            name: nodeport
            port:
              number: 8080
```

This is the response for the command:

`curl -k --connect-timeout 1 -s https://myip.mydomain.com`

```
CLIENT VALUES:
client_address=10.244.1.1 <-- ip internal to the cluster
command=GET
real path=/
query=nil
request_version=1.1
request_uri=http://myip.mydomain.com:8080/

SERVER VALUES:
server_version=nginx: 1.10.0 - lua: 10001

HEADERS RECEIVED:
accept=*/*
host=myip.mydomain.com
user-agent=curl/7.74.0
x-forwarded-for=X.X.X.122 <-- real ip of the curl client
x-forwarded-host=myip.mydomain.com
x-forwarded-port=443
x-forwarded-proto=https
x-forwarded-scheme=https
x-real-ip=X.X.X.122 <-- real ip of the curl client
x-request-id=0d67fea66435e387015cf3e9b9700c0e
x-scheme=https
BODY:
-no body in request-
```

Let's ignore the fact that Haproxy is so kind to fill up x-real-ip header with my real ip, but if I can I want to avoid to use these headers to get the real IP. The fact of the matter is that client_address is incorrect inside a Pod when using an ingress rule.

The result I'm trying to get:

```
CLIENT VALUES:
client_address=X.X.X.122 <-- real client ip here....
command=GET
```

Answer (score 0):

By default nginx ingress controller does not preserve the client IP address, you need to activate proxy protocol: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#use-proxy-protocol

You need to add the annotation to the ingress yaml definition:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-proxy-protocol: "true"
spec:
  # ...
```

When this option is activated, the Pods receiving the http requests will receive one of these headers: `X-Real-IP` or `X-Forwarded-For` on every request.

Comment: Are these options overridden when the client sets them explicitly? I remember  having hearda security issue on Stack Overflow happening due to `X-Forwarded-For` and I have also been able to use `X-Real-IP` to overwrite the IP shown in the `Last Logins` of another website. If this is not overridden, there should probably be a warning that this technique shouldn't be used/trusted in security-sensible code.

Comment: the question was not referring to the security implications of injecting the real IP address of the requests coming into a cluster. But yes, you're right, this should not be used on sensible code as the IP address can be "easily" spoofed by an external actor.

Comment: Exactly why I would like to avoid using these headers to get the real IP. The externalTrafficPolicy option in the ingress controller promises just that, by avoiding NAT you can keep the real source ip for that request.

Comment: if you don't like the suggested method on the answer, then you need to add the `proxy-real-ip-cidr` annotation indicating the cidr where the HA-proxy is located. It's a balance between security and complexity. More details here: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/miscellaneous/

Comment: As far as I understand, `proxy-real-ip-cidr` is an option to let the ingress controller trust (at layer 7) haproxy and it's headers ( `X-Forwarded-For` etc.). Proxy protocol is a layer 4 option to maintain the client IP address. However the problem I'm having is not between haproxy and the ingress controller, I managed to keep the client ip address already. This however gets lost between the ingress controller and the pod.